# Word Wrap on WebView

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-10, win-universal-app, word-wrap

I have been searching and searching and can't seem to find a solution. Is there a word wrap property for Webviews? Specifically in Universal Windows Applications.

This is my webview:

```
<WebView x:Name="body" 
  Visibility="Visible" 
  RelativePanel.Below="mySymbol"
  RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
  RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
  DefaultBackgroundColor="LightGray"
  Height="300" 
  Width="1800"
  Margin="-5,80"/>
```

I am hoping there is something equivalent to `TextWrapping="Wrap"` like I would use in a `TextBlock`....

Does anyone have any suggestions or work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapping of text displayed in a WebView will be dependent upon the HTML that is loaded in it as much as the properties (size) and visual tree of the WebView itself.

Comment: Yeah, The HTML is correct. I just had my `Webview` lying in a `RelativePanel` which seemed to neglect some of the properties of the `WebView`

Comment: @code for future reference - when there are multiple factors that could be impacting what you're seeing, it can help if you can include a complete repro in your question. In your instance the issue could have been the webview, the rest of the page it is in or the html it displays. Providing more details in your question will help you get a good answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the issue. I had my `WebView` inside of a `RelativePanel`... That looks like it keeps the `WebView` from text wrapping.

Along with setting the width and the height to `auto`